# Cannot join LAS file In QGIS with Whitebox Tools

Tags: qgis, merge, lidar, las, whitebox-tools

I have 9 .las files that I am trying to join into a single .las file in QGis. I have been using Whitebox tools plugin in QGis and when I try to select all the files and assign an output file if get this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users/peter/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\wbt_for_qgis\wbtalgorithm.py", line 187, in processAlgorithm
tmp = QgsProcessingUtils.convertToCompatibleFormat(layer, False, 'exported-{}'.format(i), ['shp'], 'shp', context, feedback)
NameError: name 'QgsProcessingUtils' is not defined

Execution failed after 0.03 seconds
```

I guess maybe the plugin is missing some function. I'm going to try updating it and running it the function from the command line. Does anyone have a work around within QGIS, or am I missing something?

I am also new to GIS and Whitebox tools.

Comment: What version of QGIS and Whitebox do you have, there is a setup video that may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJXDBsNbcTg&t=3s

Comment: You might use LAStools via the LAStools plugin, specifically the lasmerge tool.

Comment: Hi. I have been avoiding using LAStools as I do not have a license for the software and from what I know about it the software creates noise(?) in the data set if you don't have a license. Thank you for the video. My guess is that I made a mistake in the setup of whitebox tools. I was able to fix it in Python though. An answer is below.

Comment: LASMerge is free. The list of free LASTools is [>>>Here<<<](https://lastools.github.io/LICENSE.txt).

Comment: Thanks! I used whitebox tools because the clip tool was free there and is not in LAStools. But its good to know I can use LAStools for merging in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue using the Whitebox tools python module instead.

```
    def join_las_files(input_files, output_file):
    wbt = whitebox.WhiteboxTools()
    wbt.verbose = True  # Set this to False if you don't want to see WhiteboxTools output

    # Check if the input files exist
    for file in input_files:
        if not os.path.exists(file):
            print(f"Error: Input file not found: {file}")
            return

    # Join the LAS files
    input_files_str = ';'.join(input_files)
    wbt.lidar_join(input_files_str, output_file)
    print("LAS files joined successfully.")

# Replace '/path/to/input/las/' with the path to your directory containing the .las files
input_directory =  r'c:\Users\peter\OneDrive\Desktop\Prospect Park LiDAR\clipped data'
input_files = [os.path.join(input_directory, file_name) for file_name in os.listdir(input_directory) if file_name.lower().endswith(".las")]

# Replace '/path/to/output/' with the path to the output directory and 'output.las' with the desired output file name
output_directory = '/path/to/output/'
output_file = os.path.join(r'c:\Users\peter\OneDrive\Desktop\Prospect Park LiDAR\clipped data', 'output.las')

join_las_files(input_files, output_file)
```

This is not an answer within QGis, but worked for me. I then reimported the file into QGis